# When calling delete for LinkedList, variable is being assigned different memory

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am using a linked list to store information on binary bits. Degree tells which power to raise an integer, 2, to.

The problem occurs in my set_bit method. It is supposed to delete the node pointer "currentSet" once the "target" node pointer is found. However instead of setting "currentSet" to null/releasing the memory, currentSet is being given a different, lower memory address. Why is this? What am I doing wrong? The program works when I explicitly sell currentSet to nullptr but shouldn't delete currentSet do this as well?

Here is the implementation of header

```
//file is "binary.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "binary.h"

//using std::cout;

Binary::Binary(int x) {
    firstTerm = nullptr;

    while (x > 0) {
        unsigned int degree = (unsigned int) (log(float(x)) / log(float(2)));
        set_bit(1, degree);
        x -= (int) pow(float(2), float(degree));
    }
}

Binary::~Binary() {
    BinaryNode *temp;

    while (firstTerm != nullptr) {
        temp = firstTerm->next;
        delete firstTerm;
        firstTerm = temp;
    }
}

void Binary::set_bit(int bit, int degree) {
    BinaryNode *currentSet = firstTerm;
    BinaryNode *target;
    std::cout << "get_bit returns " << get_bit(degree) << std::endl;

    if (bit == 0 && get_bit(degree)) {
        std::cout << "bit = 0 " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "currentSet->degree " << currentSet->degree << std::endl;
        if (currentSet->degree == degree) {
            std::cout << "in if" << std::endl;
            firstTerm = currentSet->next;
            delete currentSet;
            std::cout << "end if" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            target = currentSet;
            std::cout << "in else" << std::endl;
            while (currentSet != nullptr) {
                if (currentSet->degree == degree) {
                    std::cout << "in nested if" << std::endl;
                    //std::cout << "currentSet->degree = " << currentSet->degree << std::endl;
                    target->next = currentSet->next;
                    std::cout << "currentSet before delete " << currentSet << std::endl;
                    delete currentSet;
                    std::cout << "currentSet " << currentSet << "\nend nested if" << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "in nested else" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "firstTerm->next = " << firstTerm->next << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "currentSet->next = " << currentSet->next << std::endl;
                    target = currentSet;
                    currentSet = currentSet->next;
                    std::cout << "currentSet->next = " << currentSet->next << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "end nested else\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (bit == 1 && get_bit(degree) == 0) {
        std::cout << "bit = 1" << std::endl;
        firstTerm = new BinaryNode(degree, firstTerm);
        /*if (firstTerm->next  nullptr) {
            currentSet = firstTerm;
        }*/
        std::cout << "firstTerm = " << firstTerm << std::endl;
        std::cout << "firstTerm->degree = " << firstTerm->degree << std::endl;
        std::cout << "firstTerm->next = " << firstTerm->next << std::endl;
    }
}

int Binary::get_bit(int degree) const {
    BinaryNode *currentGet = firstTerm;
    while (currentGet != nullptr) {
        //std::cout << "currentGet != nullptr";
        if (currentGet->degree == degree) {
            return 1;
        }
        currentGet = currentGet->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the header

```
//file is "binary.h"
#ifndef _BINARY_H_
#define _BINARY_H_
#include <iostream>

class Binary {
private:
    struct BinaryNode {
        int degree;
        BinaryNode* next;
        BinaryNode(int d, BinaryNode* n): degree(d),next(n) {}
    };
    BinaryNode *firstTerm;

public:
    // default constructor
    Binary() {
       firstTerm = nullptr;
    }

void set_bit(int b, int d);

int get_bit(int d) const;
#endif
```

Here is the tester file

```
//file is "binary_main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "binary.h"

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    cout << "\nTESTING GET AND SET METHODS" << endl;
    b1.set_bit(1, 2);
    b1.set_bit(1, 5);
    b1.set_bit(1, 0);
    b1.set_bit(0, 2);
}
```

**edited**

Comment: Regarding your loop in the destructor, think about what would happen with the first node in the list.

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to learn to use a debugger, and step through the code, line by line, to see what really happens.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thank you for the information of the destructor, it has been edited. I used the debugger (MS Visual Studio - C++) and could not figure out why the currentSet is still referencing something. I will continue to work on this.

Comment: `delete currentSet` may or may not have any visible effect on either `currentSet` or `*currentSet`. You cannot expect `currentSet` to become null after it has been `delete`d, and you cannot draw any conclusions from observing its value.

Comment: @n.m. I did not realize this. This was the problem. The delete call did not make the currentSet node to null. So I explicitly did and it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly set currentSet to nullptr,
answer was found using information from n.m.